# Making a nested nameValuePairs

Tags: java, android, httpclient

I want to make a nested nameValuePairs
something like this:

> List nameValuePairs = new ArrayList(1);
>     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key", new BasicNameValuePair("key2", "value").toString() ) );

I know this doesn't work, but what should I do to get this nesting right?

Comment: I am not aware that this sort of nesting is supported by standard HTML forms. What specifically are you expecting to send to the server?

Comment: Ruby on rails want's to get data in the form of:
{"event" => {"name" => "event_name"} }

Comment: are you trying to add value to a hash in ruby on rails?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it!

the trick was to do it like this:

> nameValuePairs.add(new
>   BasicNameValuePair("[key][key2]",
>   "value"));

Answer (score 1):

*Create json objects, and you can add json object inside json object with name value pair*

> JSONObject jsonParam1 = new JSONObject();
>   JSONObject jsonParam2 = new JSONObject();
>   JSONObject jsonParam3 = new JSONObject();
>
> jsonParam1.put("action", "add");  // add data to json object (name value pair)
>   jsonParam1.put("first_name", "sam");
>   jsonParam1.put("last_name", "sam pasas");
>   jsonParam2.put("gender", "M");
>   jsonParam2.put("dob", "12-12-2015");
>   jsonParam2.put("street_address1", "sdfsdf");
>
> //add json object inside json object (namevaluepair)
>   jsonParam3.put("details1",jsonParam1);
>   jsonParam3.put("details2",jsonParam2);    `